# How can I upload the jar file in my gradle local caches to my own nexus 3.0?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, nexus

I am using gradle to build my project , and I build a maven repository by nexus 3.6.x in our company intranet,and it can not access extranet for example maven cantral repositories. So I want to upload my gradle local caches to the maven repository I built so others can download the jar files the project needed. But their are many jar files and their dependencies, how can I batch upload them to my maven repository?

Comment: try to just copy all your .m2 directory to your nexus machine... (if it has no access to internet...)

Comment: But the nexus 3 use blob storage to store files, I can simply copy the local file to it.

Comment: Maybe a proxy to centralMaven from your company Nexus? And, for batch upload the third-party jars, I think you can just try to write some bash script. Parse out the name and apply a command on top of it to upload.